# wal2json for RedShift?

Tags: amazon-redshift

We're looking for ways to CDC from AWS RedShift.

Since RedShift is a fork of PostreSQL 8, I was thinking if it's possible to use something like [wal2json](https://github.com/eulerto/wal2json) to get CDC out of RedShift WALs.

If that's not possible, any other CDC routes for RedShift?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Redshift is not really a fork of Postgres, there is no WAL. A thin layer of Postgres is used on the Redshift leader node allowing the use of Postgres JDBC/ODBC drivers.

Also you would normally use CDC to capture small frequent changes happening in an OLTP database. Redshift is **not** an OLTP database, it is designed for batch ingestion and fast analytic queries over millions, billions, or trillions of rows.

Comment: Thanks for the answer! Good to know that there is no WAL. To your second paragraph - yes, they are looking to dup data that's in RedShift into another Big Data / OLAP distributed platform for ML/ analytics use cases that are impossible or costly to do on RedShift. And yes that CDC will scatter on tens of billions of records, but the daily rate of change is rather small and would have been totally possible to do with a CDC solution. Thx again

Comment: OK, cool. You could schedule a periodic `UNLOAD` (in parquet format) of the changed data to S3. Then you can consume the entire data set directly from S3 in another tool (EMR, Spark, etc.). https://docs.aws.amazon.com/redshift/latest/dg/r_UNLOAD.html

Comment: yes that's what we do now. We use `UNLOAD` and then load in Spark that temp table from S3. It's been slow so we were looking at a way to create a generic CDC solution out of RedShift, but looks like there is none? UNLOAD has to be crafted in a way to bring only new changes which sometimes not possible on some tables, not scalable or the solution is not generic enough. We then have to merge changes in the target table (assuming could be dups of what was offloading from UNLOAD previous and current run). Thanks again!